# WDIO: How to access variables in a describe block, that were declared in beforeAll?

Tags: webdriver-io

I have nearly 20 variables to declare, so I'd rather not declare them for each test. I wanted to declare them in a beforeAll() but I don't think that works. How can I declare a lot of variables once (in beforeAll or elsewhere), and have access to them in multiple tests?

This doesn't work:

```
const assert = require('assert');

beforeAll(() => {
  browser.url('example.com');
  // ### declare a bunch of variables ###
})

describe('something', () => {
  it('should do cool stuff', () => {
    // access a bunch of variables

  });
});
```

Nor does this:

```
const assert = require('assert');

beforeAll(() => {
  browser.url('example.com');
})

describe('something', () => {
  // ### declare a bunch of variables ###
  it('should do cool stuff', () => {
    // access a bunch of variables

  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh, I knew I was missing something easy, and I've even used this method before...

Create a file called `config.js` or whatever you want, in the same directory as your tests. Declare all of your variables in that file, like so

```
module.exports = {
  get var1 () { return browser.element(yourSelector); },
  get var2 () { return browser.element(yourSelector); },      
  ...
  get var20 () { etc },
}
```

Then at the top of your spec file, require the above file like `const gv = require('./config.js');`

Use the variables like this `gv.var1.click()` or `gv.var2.whatever()`.